# Why does my code create a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a function for downloading webpages.  I understand that libcurl works, but I refuse to use it.  I don't like the idea that some other package needs to be install for this function to work, so I want to create my own.

Anyway, things were going good until I started receiving a segmentation fault for an unknown reason.  So I reduced my code as small as possible so that the segmentation fault still occurs.  Then I tried to debug it.

The following code is what creates the segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct httpheader
{

    char cache_control[21];
    int unsigned long content_length;
    char content_type[51];
    char date[41];
    char expires[41];
    char last_modified[41];
    char location[305];
    char server[51];
    int status;
    char transfer_encoding[11];

};

int main (void)
{

    struct httpheader headerinfo;
    int buf_size = 4096;
    char buf[buf_size];
    strncpy(buf, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", buf_size);
    strncat(buf, "Date: Mon, 21 Jul 2014 20:52:38 GMT\n", buf_size);
    strncat(buf, "Server: Apache\n", buf_size);
    strncat(buf, "Set-Cookie: geofilter_country=US; path=/; domain=www.sony.com; expires=Mon, 14-Sep-2015 20:52:38 GMT\n", buf_size);
    strncat(buf, "Accept-Ranges: bytes\n", buf_size);
    strncat(buf, "Content-Length: 11978\n", buf_size);
    strncat(buf, "Content-Type: text/html\n", buf_size);

//  printf("1\n");

    set_header(&headerinfo, &buf);
    display_header(&headerinfo);

    exit(0);

}

int set_header (struct httpheader *heady, char *data)
{

    char *ptr1, *ptr2; // Used for string manipulation.
    char **dummy;

    data[12] = '\0';
    heady->status = atoi(&data[9]);
    data[12] = ' ';

    if((ptr1 = strstr(data, "Content-Length: ")) == NULL)
        heady->content_length = 0;
    else
        heady->content_length = strtoul(&ptr1[16], dummy, 10);

    heady->content_length = 0;
    strcpy(heady->date, "");
    strcpy(heady->content_type, "");
    strcpy(heady->cache_control, "");
    strcpy(heady->expires, "");
    strcpy(heady->last_modified, "");
    strcpy(heady->location, "");
    strcpy(heady->server, "");
    strcpy(heady->transfer_encoding, "");

}

int display_header (struct httpheader *heady)
{

        printf("Cache-Control     : %s\n", heady->cache_control);
        printf("Content-Length    : %d\n", heady->content_length);
        printf("Content-Type      : %s\n", heady->content_type);
        printf("Date              : %s\n", heady->date);
        printf("Expires           : %s\n", heady->expires);
        printf("Last-Modified     : %s\n", heady->last_modified);
        printf("Location          : %s\n", heady->location);
        printf("Server            : %s\n", heady->server);
        printf("Status            : %d\n", heady->status);
        printf("Transfer-Encoding : %s\n", heady->transfer_encoding);

}
```

If you look at the code you will notice a 'printf' statement that is commented out.  If you compile the code as is and run the program, a segmentation fault occurs.  If you uncomment the 'printf' statement, then compile it, the program run fine with the proper output.

Please help me understand what is going on.  Why would the lack of a 'printf' statement create a segmentation fault?

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.12.22+ (dc4@dc4-arm-01) (gcc version 4.7.2 20120731 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2458 - Linaro GCC 2012.08) ) #691 PREEMPT Wed Jun 18 18:29:58 BST 2014
$
```

EDIT:

---

Thank you for all the help received, this is an amazing community!  Anyway, I guess my problem is that 'a little knowledge is a dangerous thing'.

My understanding of the C language needs to be expanded.  Thinking that I can use a few 'printf' statements for debugging is obviously ridiculous (it works sometimes, but that isn't good enough for me).  Also, I need to return to function prototyping.  I forgot it once, and there were no problems compiling so I stopped doing it!  Well I'm back to doing it.

If crashmstr would post his comment as an answer, I would choose it.

Comment: run it under a debugger

Comment: Please read the `man` of `strncat`, this is not how `strncat` third argument works.

Comment: Why are your `set_header` and `display_header` functions declared as returning an int value, while neither of them have a `return` statement? You should either declare them as `void` or return an int.

Comment: Please also enable warnings and take heed of them (`gcc -Wall ...`).

Comment: The `char **dummy;` (uninitialized) then `strtoul(&ptr1[16], dummy, 10);` looks strange. Seen examples using `char *dummy;` then `strtoul(&ptr1[16], &dummy, 10);`... In your case, you are not even giving it an address to use.

Comment: crashmstr, thanks for that.  I wasn't sure how to use that pointer, and I didn't need it.  So I thought it was ok the way it was.  It looks like (besides all the little things I forgot) that this was the solution I was looking for.

Comment: DeepBlackDwarf, you are right about that.  I hadn't set up checking of the function call return values, so I hadn't put the returns in yet. I never use 'void' as a return type for a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for the crashes is the lacks of forward declarations in your code: when you call a function before declaring it, the compiler assumes that all formal parameters of the function are of type `int`. You should have gotten warnings about this.

Add these two lines before your `main` to fix this problem:

```
int set_header (struct httpheader *heady, char *data);
int display_header (struct httpheader *heady);
```

Here are a few additional notes on your code:

- If you want to use an ampersand, use index zero `set_header(&headerinfo, &buf[0])`
- Alternatively, you could use `buf` without an ampersand or an index
- You should not be using `strncpy`/`strncat` family of functions, because they are designed for a different purpose. It is misleading to readers who expect these functions to be used along with fixed-length strings.
- Do not ignore warnings. When C compiler reports a warning, there is almost certainly something wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm able to compile without prototype declarations.  I guess I just figured I didn't need to do that anymore with the compiler I was using because of the lack of complaints.  But it complains when debugging, so I will add them.

Comment: thats got to be a pretty ancient forgiving compiler

Comment: dasblinkenlight, you are right about the strncat.  The last argument should be "buf_size - strlen(buf) - 1".

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for the following reasons: My first choice is not available; this answer was submitted first.

Answer (score 1):

for a start

```
int set_header (struct httpheader *heady, char *data)
```

does not match

```
    char buf[buf_size];
..
    set_header(&headerinfo, &buf);
```

&buf is char ** not char*

where are your function prototypes? I expect that the compiler is complaining like mad